# Android - How to disable button Setting Wallpaper in android livewallpaper (android OS 2.1)

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

How can I disable button [Set Wallpaper] or button[Setting] in android livewallaper (OS 2.1 or higher)
If someone knows , please help me !

Answer (score 4):

To disable Settings button, you must remove "**android:settingsActivity**" property from the LiveWallpaper configuration xml.